# How does `KSComp` behave when using the options `lower_flag`, `ref`, `ref0` and `units` and `upper` at the same time?

Tags: python, constraints, openmdao

Reading the [Adding Constraints](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/core_features/adding_desvars_cons_objs/adding_constraint.html) page, I have understood that the scaling of the a constraint value happens in the following order:

- the constraint value is converted from the connected output’s units to the desired units;
- `ref0` and `ref` scale the constraint value to 0 and 1, respectively, and they have to be defined in the desired units.

My understanding is that also `lower` and `upper` have to defined in the desired units and that they are scaled according to the values of `ref0` and `ref`. Is this correct?

Now, I'm finding a little bit trickier to understand what happens with `KSComp`. Say I have the following situation:

- the connected output feeds an array of stiffnesses defined in N/mm;
- the `KSComp` component is defined with the following options: `lower_flag=True`, `units=N/m` and `upper=1`, meaning that the stiffnesses will be defined in N/m and will be constrained to be larger than 1.

My understanding is that the array of stiffnesses will be converted to N/m and then the component will transform the input array and calculate the KS function such that the constraint is satisfied if it is less than zero.

How should I use `ref0` and `ref` in this case? In theory they should represent the physical values in the desired units that map to 0 and 1, respectively. However, looking at the [source code of `KSComp`](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/_modules/openmdao/components/ks_comp.html) it seems that the scaling is applied to the computed KS function. In this case, if I only use the `ref` option and I scale a feasible value to 1, this will never satisfy the constraint, because with the option `add_constraint=True` the constraint is set to be satisfied when the KS function si smaller than 0 (0 scales to 0). Am I getting any of this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a constraint the values of `lower`, `upper`, `scaler`, `adder`, `ref` and `ref0` should all be applied in the units of the constraint.

The KS function behind KS comp can be a bit difficult to scale because it produces an output that is somewhat nonintuitive.

I massaged the `add_constraint` example from the docs to make `upper` easily changed, and had the example just run the model rather than optimize it.

It prints out the quantity `KS` being produced (and constrained) by the KSComp. This quantity is positive when violated, so 0 is probably a good value for `ref0` (which is the default.  Playing around with values for `upper` indicates that the nominal value of `KS` is about the same order of magnitude of the distance from the constraint.  So if your initial guess has a minimum distance of `3000` units from `upper`, the out `KS` will be on the same order of magnitude, `3000`.

If we assume to scale this so that the nominal constraint values have a magnitude of `1` (not always the best assumption but a reasonable one), then an appropriate value for `ref` in this case is `3000`.

(I think it's always best to let `ref` be positive).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import openmdao.api as om

n = 50
upper = -40
prob = om.Problem()
model = prob.model

prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()

model.add_subsystem('ivc', om.IndepVarComp('x', val=np.ones(n,), units='N/mm'))

model.add_subsystem('comp', om.ExecComp('y = 3.0*x**2 + k',
                                        x={'val': np.zeros((n, )), 'units': 'N/m'},
                                        y={'val': np.zeros((n, )), 'units': 'N/m'},
                                        k=0.0), promotes_inputs=['x', 'k'])

model.add_subsystem('ks', om.KSComp(width=n, lower_flag=True, upper=upper,
                                    ref=40, add_constraint=True))

model.add_design_var('k', lower=-100, upper=100)
model.add_objective('k', scaler=1)

model.connect('comp.y', 'ks.g')

prob.setup()
prob.set_val('x', np.linspace(-np.pi/2, np.pi/2, n))
prob.set_val('k', 5.)

prob.run_driver()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = prob.get_val('x')
y = prob.get_val('comp.y')
ks = prob.get_val('ks.KS')

print(f'KS = {ks}')

ax.plot(x, y, 'r.')
ax.plot(x, upper*np.ones_like(x), 'k--')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.grid(True)
ax.text(-0.25, 0, f"k = {prob.get_val('k')[0]:6.3f}")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, I understand what you mentioned about the initial distance from `upper`, it makes sense to use such value for `ref`. I am still trying to understand what the optimizer sees when the KS function is scaled, since in `ks_comp.py` the `self.add_constraint` call has the hardcoded argument `upper=0.0`. I guess this internal value of `upper` is scaled coherently with the KS function, so that while we see the constraint satisfied for negative function value, the optimizer sees the constraint satisfied for a function value smaller than the scaled value of `upper`, right?

Comment: The KSComp formulation is admittedly really confusing.  You want a lower bound but have to specify upper?  That's crazy.  I believe you're correct about the internal scaling. I'm hoping that a new library of helper math functions that include smoothed things like tanh activations and ks functions can help remove some of that confusion.